# Retrofit 2/Rxjava - retrieve headers from response

Tags: java, http-headers, retrofit2, rx-java2

```
@GET("/city/{cityId}/category/all")
Observable<MyDictionary> getDictionaries(@Path(value = "cityId", encoded = true) String cityId, @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers);
```

Call method to retrieve data:

```
service.getDictionaries(cityId, headersMap)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(resp ->
                {
                     /*...............*/

                }, throwable ->
                {
                     /*...............*/
                });
```

I can get reposne eaisly. But I also need to know response headers. How to access them in my code? Any tips? I'm getting only body, how to get headers also?

Comment: let me know if my answer worked.

Answer (score 5):

You can get response `headers` this way:

Set response type as `Observable<Response<MyDictionary>>` as following:

**In Service Interface:**

```
@GET("/city/{cityId}/category/all")
Observable<Response<MyDictionary>> getDictionaries(@Path(value = "cityId", encoded = true) String cityId, @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers);
```

**and while calling api:** you would be able to get headers by :

`response.getHeaders()` method.